# How do i return expanded widgets from ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter

I have tried to return a list of widgets in horizontal direction, i want to expand widgets width dynamically. how can i achieve this. (Note: ListView.builder placed inside column)

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: widget.playType.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Flex(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                color: colorSubMenuBg,
                height: 45,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    widget.playType[index],
                    style: CustomTextStyle.listTile4(context),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
```

**Expected output should be like this highlighted part:**

[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

Comment: i'm getting this error

Comment: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#663dd relayoutBoundary=up23 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: if i remove Flex widget i get the output, but each List Item taking minimum width

Comment: you have  to put  some kind of constraints on your width because you are in a ```ListView``` you have infinite width and you are saying take up infinite space

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Container( height: 70)in your ListViewBuilder()

like this

````
 Container(
            height: 70,
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: widget.playType.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Flex(
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                            color: colorSubMenuBg,
                            height: 45,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.playType[index],
                                style: CustomTextStyle.listTile4(context),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          );```
````

Comment: i already wrapped ListView.builder with Container, it's not working

Comment: did you give a height ?

Answer (score 0):

Actual working code, i removed flex from ListView.builder and added width for ListItems and ListView.

```
var buttonListWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
Container(

                  height: 45,
                  width: buttonListWidth,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: widget.playType.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: colorSubMenuBg,
                            height: 45,
                            width: buttonListWidth / widget.playType.length,
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.playType[index],
                                style: CustomTextStyle.listTile4(context),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Row over the ListView.builder and add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` property to that Row.

Answer (score 0):

ItemExtent property of ListView.builder

```
itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / LENGHT,
```

Comment: It's the only REAL solution